# How to convert this list to int

Tags: python, list, int

I have the following list:

```
[['3*4'],
 ['7*8*1'],
 ['8*2*4']]
```

And I want to convert that to int like this and it should caluclate the figures:

```
[[12],[56],[64]]
```

this is what ive already tried:

```
newList= list(map(int, oldList))
```

How to do that?

Comment: use `eval` or a safer expression evaluator. Note that you have nested lists, not just lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
newlist = [[eval(v[0])] for v in oldlist]
```

or perhaps the somewhat more-pythonic

```
newlist = [[eval(v)] for v, *w in oldlist]
```

Either uses a list comprehension to look at each sub-list in your given list, take the string out of the list, evaluate it to an integer value, then wrap that integer in a list into your new sub-list.

Note that `eval` is dangerous and should be used only for your own strings. If you input such a string, the user could type something that would format your hard drive or do other nasty things.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between converting a string to an integer and evaluating an expression.

Here you want the latter.

This can be achieved with `eval()`.

```
l = [['3*4'],
     ['7*8*1'],
     ['8*2*4']]
out = [[eval(j) for j in i] for i in l]
#[[12], [56], [64]]
```

---

Note that the `eval()` built-in is potentially unsafe if called on unsanitised user input (e.g. they could make system calls).

Answer (score 0):

this is kinda odd to do, but you can do it with `split`:

```
initial_list = [['3*4'],
 ['7*8*1'],
 ['8*2*4']]

new_list = []
for mini_list in initial_list:
    multiplier = 1
    for number in mini_list[0].split('*'):
        multiplier *= int(number)
    new_list.append([multiplier])

print(new_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[[12], [56], [64]]
```